# Get element of a tuple via function argument rather than template parameter

Tags: c++, tuples

For example, I have a tuple

```
std::tuple<T0, T1, T2> tp;
```

where T0, T1, and T2 inherit from T. I want to get its element's base class pointer like

```
T* get(i)(tp);
```

other than

```
(T*)(&std::get<i>(tp));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a wrapper function as:

```
T* get(int index, std::tuple<T0, T1, T2> & tp)
{
   if ( index < 0 || index > 2 ) throw std::out_of_range("index");
   else if ( index == 0 ) return &std::get<0>(tp);
   else if ( index == 1 ) return &std::get<1>(tp);
   else return &std::get<2>(tp);
}
```

Since `T0`, `T1` and `T2` derive from `T`, so you don't need to use cast.

You probably also would like to overload this function for `std::tuple<T0, T1, T2> const &` in which case the function will return `T const*`.

Comment: If the tuple_size is varying, how to do it?

Comment: @user1899020: It cannot vary. If it is `N`, then it is `N`. It cannot change.